# Inconsistent behavior of Java Maven Modules in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have created a Maven Java parent project in Eclipse `(MavProj)`.  Within it I have created two child modules `(MavMod1 and MavMod2)`.  For all three I used `maven-archetype-quickstart`.  My package explorer view looks like this:

[image]
On purpose I have introduced a compile error in the class `org.MavMod1.App`.

When I view the file via the parent Maven project, I don't see the compile error, as can be seen below:
[image]

When I see the **same file** via the Maven module, I can see the compile error, as can be seen below:
[image]

---

Is there a way I can see the compile error when I view the file via the parent Maven project also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file with the error is not in any source folder of the parent project, therefor that error is not relevant to the parent and it is only displayed in the module project. I would say this behavior is expected.

If you use the *project explorer* instead of the *package explorer*, you can activate the [Nested/Hierarchical view of projects](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M5/#nested-projects) setting. With that setting the modules will be nested in the parent project and you will see all files only once, with the compiler error.